# How to disable Safe Mode on jekyll-asciidoc plugin

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions, asciidoctor

I am importing an external file using the "jekyll-asciidoc"
plugin.

```
[source,groovy]
----
include::   {projectdir}/src/test/resources/examples/abc.groovy[tags=example1,indent=0]
----
```

Jekyll doesn't want to include that file because it is outside the folder of my website. That is the message:

```
asciidoctor: WARNING: include file has illegal reference to ancestor of jail, auto-recovering
```

How can I disable the asciidoctor "Safe Mode" from the Jekyll configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
asciidoctor:
  safe: 0
```

Comment: Yes, it works. My error was putting that option under the attributes section.